# Why does the Rayleigh Quotient converge to eigenvalues quadratically?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My textbook says that for real symmetric matrix $A$ with eigenvectors $q_1, \ldots, q_m$, the Rayleigh quotient $r(x)$ for some vector $x$ will satisfy

$$r(x) - r(q_J) = \mathcal{O}(\|x - q_J\|^2)$$

as $x \to q_J$.

They prove most of this statement as follows. Write $x = \sum_{i=1}^m a_iq_i$, so $r(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2 \lambda_i / \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2$. If we assume $|a_i / a_J| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $i \neq J$, then the book says that it is easy to see that $r(x) - r(q_J) = \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$.

My question is twofold:

1. How do they derive that "easy to see" conclusion?
2. How does this relate to the original bound with $\|x - q_J\|^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
|r(x)-r(q_J)|
&=\left|\frac{\sum_ia_i^2\lambda_i}{\sum_ia_i^2}-\lambda_J\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{\sum_{i}a_i^2(\lambda_i-\lambda_J)}{\sum_{i}a_i^2}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{\sum_{i\ne J}(a_i/a_J)^2(\lambda_i-\lambda_J)}{\sum_{i\ne J}(a_i/a_J)^2+1}\right|\\
&\le\sum_{i\ne J}(a_i/a_J)^2|\lambda_i-\lambda_J|\\
&\le(m-1)\,\varepsilon^2\max_{i\ne J}|\lambda_i-\lambda_J|.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer -- this makes sense. However, I'm still unclear on how this relates to the bound $\mathcal{O}(\|x -q_J\|^2)$

Comment: @greg115 Merely that $|a_i/a_J|<\varepsilon$ does not imply that $x$ is close to $q_J$. We also need $a_J$ to be close to $1$. So, say, when $|a_J-1|<\varepsilon$, we have $\|x-q_J\|^2=\sum_{i\ne J}a_i^2+(a_J-1)^2=a_J^2\sum_{i\ne J}\left(\frac{a_i}{a_J}\right)^2+(a_J-1)^2\le(1+\varepsilon)^2(m-1)\varepsilon^2+\varepsilon^2=O(\varepsilon^2)$.